# Removing duplicity of items in list of lists based on a specific index #Python

Tags: python, list

I have the following lists:

```
lista = [1,2,3,5]
listb = [1,5,2,6]
listc = [3,5,1,6]
mainList = [lista,listb,listc]
```

I'd like to remove listb from mainList since it contains the same element as lista at index position[0].

Kinda like the code below, however, applied to every list contained in mainList. basically, remove all lists with index 0 duplicity while maintaining the first one.

```
if lista[0] == listb[0]:
    mainList.remove(listb)

#But to include duplicity in for all elements in mainList.
```

Anybody?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the *result* you expect?

Comment: So, keep track of the first elements using a set, `firsts = set()` then create a new list, `result = []`, the loop over the main list and only add if you haven't seen the first index `for row in mainLIst: if row[0] not in firsts: result.append(row); firsts.add(row[0])`, or using the ordering of `dict` objects, `list(reversed({row[0]:row for row in reversed(mainList)}.values()))` but that's a bit too cutesy

Comment: The expected result is a mainList = [lista,listc]. Thanks for the code! I'll to learn your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
lista = [1,2,3,5]
listb = [1,5,2,6]
listc = [3,5,1,6]
listd = [1,7,9,4]
liste = [3,7,4,8]
mainList = [lista,listb,listc,listd,liste]
for o,i in enumerate([n for n,k in enumerate(mainList) if any([k[0]==j[0] for j in mainList[:n]])]):
     del mainList[i-o]
print(mainList) # [[1, 2, 3, 5], [3, 5, 1, 6]]
```

alternatively you can create a new list with the one line list comprehension:

```
newList = [k for n,k in enumerate(mainList) if not any([k[0]==j[0] for j in mainList[:n]])]
```

The fast solution is this:

```
firsts = set()
result = []
for k in mainList:
    if not firsts.__contains__(k[0]):
        result.append(k)
        firsts.add(k[0])
print(result)
```

or in place like this:

```
firsts = set()
i=0
while i<len(mainList):
    if not mainList[i][0] in firsts:
        firsts.add(mainList[i][0])
        i+=1
    else:
        del mainList[i]
print(mainList)
```

Comment: This looks amazingly clean but complex. It works perfectly though! I'm going to try and learn all the tools you used here.

Comment: You should try to learn tho. Enumerate gives you the index and value of each element in the list, any as the name implies checks if any element in the list is true and [:] just slices a list. If you understand those 3 concepts this code should make sense.

Comment: This really isn't an ideal approach at all, though. It is quadratic time when this can be done trivially in linear time

Comment: Fair enough. I added the set implementation for posterity.

Comment: Well, lots learned from my first posted question here. Couldn't have asked for better help all over this thread. Thanks for putting out one more implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below-

```
lista = [1,2,3,5]
listb = [1,5,2,6]
listc = [3,5,1,6]
mainList = [lista,listb,listc]
ml_final = mainList.copy()    #make a copy of the main list, this would be the final list

first_ele = []     #make empty list where first elements of all the lists are added
for i in range(len(mainList)):
  temp = mainList[i][0]
  if temp in first_ele:
    ml_final.pop(i)
  else:
    first_ele.append(temp)

#output
print(ml_list)
#[[1, 2, 3, 5], [3, 5, 1, 6]]
```

Comment: Implementation works! Thanks for the script